# If each pair of points lie in some connected subset of K, then K is connected.

Tags: proof-verification, connectedness

> If each pair of points $x,y\in K$ lie in some connected subset $K_{{x_0}x}\subset K$, then K is connected.

Fix $x_0\in K$. By hypothesis, $\forall x\in K,\exists K_{x_{0}x}\subset K$ such that $K_{x_{0}x}$ is connected. Then, $x_0\in\displaystyle{\bigcap_{x\in  K}K_{x_{0}x}}.$

Since $K_{{x_0}x}$ is connected $\forall x\in K $ and $\displaystyle{\bigcap_{x\in  K}K_{x_{0}x}}\not=\varnothing$, and so by rose petal theorem $\displaystyle{\bigcup_{x\in  K}K_{x_{0}x}}$ is connected. Since $K_{{x_0}x}\subset K$, then K is connected.

I am not really sure about the conclusion, so I would appreciate the feedback.

> Note: Rose petal theorem: If $K_\gamma$ is connected, $\forall\gamma\in\Gamma$, and $\displaystyle{\bigcap_{\gamma\in\Gamma}K_\gamma}\not=\varnothing$, then $\displaystyle{\bigcup_{\gamma\in\Gamma}K_\gamma}$ is connected.

Comment: Yeah, your last sentence (before you edited it and after) doesn’t work. Just because one set is a subset of $K$ doesn’t let you conclude that $K$ is connected. You have shown that $\displaystyle{\bigcup_{x\in  K}K_{x_{0}x}}$ is connected, so can you show that $K=\displaystyle{\bigcup_{x\in  K}K_{x_{0}x}}$?

Comment: @SteveKass I have to admit, I am not entirely sure how to go about showing that..

Comment: To show $A = B$, we typically show that $A \subset B$ and then show $B \subset A$. Is either of these easy for you in this case?

Comment: @JohnHughes I do know that, however I am self-teaching so I am not entirely sure how to apply it in this case as I have not done anything like this previously.

Comment: Consider an $x\in K$. Can you show that $x$ is in one of the sets $K_{x_{0}x}}$? If you can, then you can conclude that every element of $K$ is in the union $\displaystyle{\bigcup_{x\in  K}K_{x_{0}x}}$ (because if each $x\in K$ is in one of the sets, $K$ is in the union by the definition of union). That shows that $K$ is a subset of $\displaystyle{\bigcup_{x\in  K}K_{x_{0}x}}$. The reverse containment should be fairly easy to show. (If each set in a collection of sets is a subset of $K$, the union of the sets in the collection is also a subset of $K$.)

Comment: Why does $K_{x_0x}$ depend on an unspecified $x_0$ and not on $y$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That is what is given, I was to provide detailed conclusion. I am also confused by the notation.

Comment: @SteveKass As I mentioned notation was throwing me off, I did figure the second portion, but I was not sure of the first part of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or simply indirectly:
Assume $K$ is not connected, so $K= U\cup V$ with disjoint non-empty open $U,V$.
Pick $x\in U$, $y\in V$ accordingly and assume $x,y\in K_{xy}$. Then $U,V$ show that $K_{xy}$ is not connected ...

Comment: +1. But do you know what the "rose petal theorem" is that was referred to above?  I  like the name.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг  Rose petal theorem: If $C_\gamma$ is connected, $\forall\gamma\in\Gamma$, and $\displaystyle{\bigcap_{\gamma\in\Gamma}C_\gamma}\not=\varnothing$, then $\displaystyle{\bigcup_{\gamma\in\Gamma}C_\gamma}$ is connected.

Comment: @YoloSatoshi Thank you.